Unzip "zip" files while using devcontainer on windows
I have a small python application where the
Project Stucture is
my-app
    |
     -- .devcontainer
        |
         -- Dockerfile
        |
         -- devcontainer.json
    |
     -- convert.py
    |
     -- org.zip
    |
     -- tpp.zip

I have created a
.devcontainer on the project folder
I have added steps like this on Dockerfile
Dockerfile
RUN unzip /app/tpp.zip -d /app/tpp

RUN unzip /app/org.zip -d /app

RUN chmod +x /app/tpp/*

devonctainer.json
{
    "name": "tool",
    "build": {
        "dockerfile": "Dockerfile",
        "context": "../"
    }
    , "customizations": {
        
        "vscode": {
            
            "settings": { 
            },
            "extensions": [
                "ms-python.python",
                "ms-python.vscode-pylance"
            ]
        }
    }
    ,
    "containerEnv":{
        "ContEnv": "${localEnv: ContEnv}",
        "DEBUG" : "${localEnv:DEBUG}"
    }
}

When I open this project on the Devcontainer mode, The files tpp.zip and org.zip not unzipping
How to resolve the issue. I should use these zip files there, they are executable files.
When I run the convert.py these two unzip files will be used in the code.
This has worked on the container without any issue.
